# Get Form data from the input fields Which names are generated by model dynamically into the controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-3.0

I have a controller as given below

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoginResult()
    {
        //want get the data here
        return View();
    }
```

and I have a view in which I am rendering a view by using a model as given below

```
@model IEnumerable<My.Models.SurveyData>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Survey Form</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginResult", "My"))
    {        
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <h4> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Question)</h4>
                <br />

            @if ((int)item.InputType == 1)
            {

                <input type="text" id="@item.Id" name="@item.Id" value="" />
            }
            else if ((int)item.InputType == 2)
            {
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="@item.Id" name="@item.Id"></textarea>
            }
            else if (item.InputType.ToString().Trim().ToLower() == "checkbox")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < @item.NumberOfChoice; i++)
                {
                    <input type=@item.InputType.ToString().Trim().ToLower() name="@item.AdminAnswers.ElementAt(i).Answer"></input>@item.AdminAnswers.ElementAt(i).Answer
                    <br />
                }
            }

        }
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
}
```

Now I want to get All the input fields value on form submission into the LoginResult Method which is in Controller named "My",but all the input fields name will come dynamically. so how can I get this values in the method.

Comment: PLease check my solution

Comment: @Dilip which solution are you talking about? I didnot get you. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Use a list instead and replace your `foreach` loop with a `for` loop:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) 
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].IP)           
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x[i].Checked)// input your model item
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].IP)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
}
```

In your Contoller Action

```
[HttpPost]

  public ActionResult LoginResult(IEnumerable<SurveyData> surveyData)
  {

  }
```

Comment: in My controller action why should I pass this surveyData collection? I did not get you

Comment: you should pass it so as to get the posted data from the view to your contorller

Comment: I am not getting data from view into controller. It shows me null into the surveyData

Comment: have you used forloop instead of foreach as metnioned

Answer (score 0):

```
You just have to put model in your Post method like this:

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult  LoginResult(IEnumerable<My.Models.SurveyData>   model)
{
    //Here you can access your model data

    //want get the data here
    return View();
}
Also do following change in your View :

 @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginResult", "My", FormMethod.Post))
{   
    // Your current code
}
```

Comment: but inside the LoginResult method how can I access the input field values